# What is the right tool to cut a clothesline made of coated steel?

Tags: wiring, steel, cutting

I have a clothesline that is made of 5-6 braided tiny steel wires that is coated with flexible plastic. I need to cut it to smaller segments, I tried using a cable cutter made of carbon steel but it barely worked and the wires kept fraying or wrapping around the blades but not getting cut.

The cutter itself is losing its edges despite being new and of decent quality, I believe it is made for electrical wires made of softer materials like copper and aluminum, not steel. I would like to avoid fraying because that can be painful if hands come in contact with them by mistake.

Here is a picture of the clothesline:

[image: clothesline coated steel wire]

Answer (score 25):

I use what are generically called "**tin snips**". True tin snips are designed for thin, relatively soft material (like sheet tin or similar metal). But the good ones can cut through almost anything. I had a recent problem (very long story...short version here) where I ended up with a screw stuck inside an oven hinge and after trying all kinds of things, I pulled out my trusty tin snips and chopped off the screw.

Alternatively, go for **bolt cutters**. They are designed to cut through solid bolts, but can also cut through cables and other things. They just aren't designed to chip away at a long run like tin snips.

Comment: Yeah, I'd suggest (relatively small) bolt cutters.

Comment: Bolt cutters have a "mashing" action where the two opposing jaws meet.  This leads to squish and deforming the wires in the layup.  If it was the only option then perhaps, but there are other options too.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest attacking screws with a *good* set of tin snips that you want to use for their intended purpose of making clean, straight cuts in sheet materials.  They can cut through a lot of things, but at some point you're also doing damage to the blades.

Comment: @J... I've had this particular set for several years. Bought them for one project. Used them at various times for various things. After an hour of struggling with this particular problem, I remembered them and decided to try. They worked, much better than I expected. Yes, blades probably a little more beat up than they were before, but unquestionably the best tool for the job of what I had on hand. If I had to call a pro for help (which I came close to doing) that would have cost more than a replacement tin snips. Sometimes you improvise and it works.

Comment: You may try hacksaw, 32-40 TPI blade.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Absolutely - it was just a caveat for anyone who might consider trying it also, not that those particular considerations would necessarily apply to everyone.

Comment: @user263983 A hacksaw is a good idea here. The only catch - same as with a Dremel, etc. - is that you have to have the cable being cut secured very well when you are working on it.

Comment: Not all bolt cutters work well with steel ropes of the same diameter. Problem as OP already have - wires can get tangled up, instead of snapped.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Unfortunately, I couldn't find any decent tin snips with a tight gap where I live. The bolt cutters that I found are too large as well. I ended up using the cable cutter that I bought earlier while applying enough tension to the rope. It is a bit more manageable now.

Answer (score 19):

Cable cutters are the tool designed for cutting cable.  If you're doing this a lot, the correct tool helps.  For a one-off task, it may not be worth the cost, although then you have the tool for life.

Cable Cutters are basically scissors/tin snips but with curved blades, so the wire being cut is trapped and cannot squish out the mouth.  I use something like this for trimming the braided wires on a bicycle's brakes.

[image]

There are also fancy ones that use a ratchetting mechanism to cut beefier **copper** cables and wires.  These would be for heavy duty mains wiring or automotive starter cable, and are far too big for this task.  This one clearly says "not for steel" on the blade.  You want the top one.

[image]

Comment: @user263983 the big ones, yes.  Is written clearly on the side of the blade, and I said "is for mains wiring and automotive"  but didn't clearly say that in the text.  Good catch.

Comment: both of them. from upper image blades  sharpened for copper. steel need another angle and harder material. I own like this.

Comment: [Klein tools makes some cutters like these](https://www.kleintools.com/catalog/high-leverage-cable-cutters/high-leverage-cable-cutter-0). They say: "Cable cutter cuts 4/0 aluminum, 2/0 soft copper, 100-pair 24 AWG communications cable". _Not steel_.

Comment: In fact I just noticed Klein's tool has "NOT FOR STEEL" etched right on it. The cutters in your picture probably have no such disclaimer because any marking step would not be economical at their cheap price.

Comment: @Criggie while I agree with others about the cable cutters not being good for cutting steel wires, even tiny diameter ones like the ones I have, adding enough tension to the wire and using the cable cutter did a good enough job given the limited availability of tools, especially quality ones, where I live.

Answer (score 18):

An abrasive cutting disk works well. That might take the form of an angle grinder or a rotary tool (often generically called by the Dremel brand name).

Comment: Would be cautious using a rotating cutter disk on something like a clothesline.  They don't like to stay in place well.

Comment: I'm not sure anyone is suggesting that cuts be made while mounted as a clothesline.

Comment: This is what I do. A very thin abrasive wheel will cut through the vinyl and the wire quickly and cleanly, leaving virtually no fray. It helps to lay the rope on a block of wood or clamp it in a vice.

Comment: A secured bench vise would hold the wire for cutting nicely.  I would not recommend holding the wire as you cut it.

Comment: This is what I would suggest.   Really you can use the cheapest discs you can find.   I have cut this exact type of thing, rebar, fencing whatever with the el-cheapos from HF.    Yea they are done after going through 5-6 thick strands of rebar and might be done after cutting this 10-20 times... but they are like 8 for $5 and you aren't messing up another tool that actually needs to be precise.   The tin snips, cable cutters, whatever... holy cow you are going to f&%$ up the blade after a few cuts.

Comment: I would submit, @DMoore, that if you're ruining your cable cutters by cutting cable with them, that you're not buying a quality tool (or, perhaps, you're buying another tool cross-labeled as a "cable cutter", or one not designed for steel wire). Of course, there's nothing wrong with an el cheapo tool for a one-off task, but if you're doing it regularly... ;)

Comment: @FreeMan - I try to give answer based on who is asking the question.   I wouldn't expect joe average home owner to own cable cutters that I would trust cutting these without damage.   Anyone though doing DIY should have a cheap angle grinder because if you don't have one you a looking at spending a ton of time doing certain things (especially demo) and buying a bunch of different tools.   A $30 angle grinder can get rid of about 30 other tools.   The 30cent discs make cuts just as good as the diamond discs when you don't care how the cut looks.

Comment: Fair enough, @DMoore

Answer (score 10):

I would use a hammer and chisel on steel plate.  Not a wood chisel but a cold chisel for steel.  Lay line over a solid piece of steel, place chisel at cut point, and hit chisel with heavy type of hammer.

Answer (score 5):

As I have them for bike cables, I prefer to use my [Draper Wire Rope cutters](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Draper-Expert-57768-Wire-Cutters/dp/B0001K9WXA), but I have also used cheap [cable cutters](https://www.ebay.co.uk/p/1604315131?iid=143581254715), sometimes called fencing snips.  Tin snips tend to push the wire out after cutting the housing, and my aviation shears aren't great on anything other that sheet material.

I have a selection of electrical wire cutters and combination pliers; none of those are as suitable, but I wouldn't want to blunt my good ones on steel anyway.

Answer (score 4):

I would use a hacksaw. Wrapping the cut point in a bit of strong tape will help to keep the cut clean.

Ideally hold the cable in a vice or a pair of pliers at the least.
All of the other answers have their points, but I would have thought that a hacksaw is more universal, and even if you have nothing then a "junior hacksaw" costs only a few pennies, almost certainly far cheaper than any of the other alternatives.

Comment: Not a good call. You will never, ever get a clean cut without snags and burrs. Sure it'll cut the wire (eventually) but it won't meet the OP's requirements.

Comment: You'll get a clean cut if you do it carefully, certainly clean enough in my opinion for a clothes line - can always tape or shrink-wrap the free end if necessary. I see no indication that the OP is looking for a perfect solution - a bad pair of snips will make far more of a mess.

Answer (score 2):

Cutting steel wire requires a hardened tool with a relatively blunt, durable edge. [Diagonal cutters](https://www.kleintools.com/catalog/high-leverage-diagonal-cutting-pliers/diagonal-cutting-pliers-heavy-duty-high-leverage-8-inch) are the proper tool:

[image]

The manufacturer of the pictured tool describes their intended use:

> Diagonal Cutters cut ACSR [aluminum conductor steel reinforced], screws, nails and most hardened wire

Many pliers have a cutting section near the hinge for this purpose, for example these [long nose pliers](https://www.kleintools.com/catalog/insulated-long-nose-pliers/long-nose-pliers-insulated-6-inch):

[image]

Look around your toolbox, it's likely you already have such a tool.

Bypass cutters, those that have two blades that pass by each other like scissors, are not designed to cut steel, though with a high quality tool and thin wire you might abuse them for that purpose. For example, [Klein Tools](https://www.kleintools.com/catalog/high-leverage-cable-cutters/high-leverage-cable-cutter-0) makes these cutters which are *not reccomended*:

[image]

Notice the manufacturer says these cut copper and aluminum, which are substantially softer than steel:

> Cable cutter cuts 4/0 aluminum, 2/0 soft copper, 100-pair 24 AWG communications cable

And if you look carefully at the tool, it says "NOT FOR STEEL" near the hinge.

The problem is the sharp blade is relatively thin compared to diagonal cutters, and so it will become nicked or bent with use until the blades no longer slide smoothly against each other. A quality tool will be hardened enough to tolerate this abuse for a little while. Cheap bypass cutters will be damaged on first use, if they manage to cut your wire at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to be doing a lot of this, I'd recommend a Felco "C7" cable cutter, which looks like:

[image: Felco C7]

It's made specifically for cutting this kind of steel cable. It's not cheap, but it will be a lot easier to use than a regular pair of diagonal cutters.

Answer (score 1):

For cable this small, go with a bicycle cable cutter. They are relatively inexpensive, and will stand up to cutting even stainless cables.

For connecting the cable ends, use either the u-bolt clamps (two of them to be sure), or aluminum crimps that are made for that size cable.  Of course, if you get the crimps, you'll need to get a crimping tool.

Answer (score 1):

Earlier today, my son and I discovered that someone had borrowed and not returned the long-nose pliers that we usually use for cutting a new clotheslines to size. We tried (very gently and only once) my all-in-one RJ45 tool, two pairs of kitchen scissors, and a pair of bypass pruners. I wouldn't recommend any of these for the task.

Then I remembered I had a tiny pair of needlenose pliers that I keep in my bike toolkit, because my dad gave them to me 45 years ago and they're still often useful. Its cutting section wasn't up to the task, but we were able to use it to grasp individual filaments and twist them until they snapped, which was fast and easy work.

It left quite a ragged end, which doesn't meet the OP's requirements, but someday I'll get the right tool back and go trim the end properly, and in the meantime we have our clothesline working again.

Answer (score 0):

This stuff should be cuttable readily with a wire snip. Even a good pliers would shear it on the jaw's outer notch.

Answer (score 0):

Years ago, I was making memory wire bracelets and bought a heavy metal snip because everything I read advised against using my good metal snips that I use for other types of jewelry wire.  Memory wire is steel wire that comes in  coils in 3 sizes for bracelets, necklaces or rings.  It is steel wire that maintains its shape in the coil even after beads are added.  I keep the heavy snips with my household tools instead of my jewelry tools and take them out when I have any heavy wire to cut. They were less expensive than buying good metal snips from jewelry supply companies and came from the hardware store.  Get the heaviest ones you can find and use them for cutting steel wire.  I hope they work on your clothesline.  I think the advice to put the line in a vice is good; also wear eye protection.